# Generate dynamic xtrareport

Tags: devexpress

I want to generate dynamic `XtraReport` using DevExpress but for each Employee I want the details of it on new page of same pdf file.

```vb
Dim queryString As String = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Test where Status='P' order by EmployeeCode")

Dim adap As SqlDataAdapter
adap = New SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connectionString)
Dim rowsCount As Integer = -1
rowsCount = adap.Fill(ds)

Dim label As New XRLabel()
label.Width = 500
label.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 10.0F, FontStyle.Bold)
PageHeader1.Controls.Add(label)

If rowsCount > 0 Then
    Dim padding As Integer = 5
    Dim tableWidth As Integer = Me.PageWidth - Me.Margins.Left - Me.Margins.Right - padding * 2

    Dim dynamicTable As XRTable = XRTable.CreateTable(New Rectangle(padding, 1, tableWidth, 40), 1, 0) ' table column count

    dynamicTable.Width = tableWidth
    dynamicTable.Rows.FirstRow.Width = tableWidth
    dynamicTable.Borders = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.None

    dynamicTable.BorderWidth = 0
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    dynamicTable.BeginInit()
    For Each dc As DataColumn In ds.Tables(0).Columns

        Dim cell As New XRTableCell()

        Dim binding As New XRBinding("Text", ds, ds.Tables(0).Columns(i).ColumnName)
        cell.DataBindings.Add(binding)
        cell.CanGrow = False
        cell.CanShrink = True
        cell.TextAlignment = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.TextAlignment.MiddleCenter
        'cell.WidthF = 10
        'cell.Width = 20
        cell.Text = dc.ColumnName
        dynamicTable.Rows.FirstRow.Cells.Add(cell)
        i += 1
    Next dc

    dynamicTable.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8.0F)
    dynamicTable.AdjustSize()
    dynamicTable.EndInit()
    Detail.Controls.Add(dynamicTable)
    'label.Text = String.Format("Data table: {0}", Test)

    Me.DataSource = ds
    Me.DataMember = Test

Else
    label.Text = String.Format("There's no data to display or the table doesn't exists")
End If
```

Comment: what problem you are getting in it.. you just setting header in this code snippet.. where is cells and their binding to display information of employee??

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not have much information that what are you exactly want to accomplish. I suspect that you are trying to know that how to setup dynamic data based on your Dataset.

Check the below code snippet, which adds header table(for displaying columns name) and details table(for displaying employee in your code snippet). If you are having problem setting the cells width or styles etc then go through the below example and correct your report as you want to make it up.

From: [How to create a report dynamically in the WinForms application](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4657)

```
Public Sub InitDetailsBasedonXRTable(ByVal rep As XtraReport)
            Dim ds As DataSet = (CType(rep.DataSource, DataSet))
            Dim colCount As Integer = ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count
            Dim colWidth As Integer = (rep.PageWidth - (rep.Margins.Left + rep.Margins.Right)) / colCount

            ' Create a table to represent headers
            Dim tableHeader As New XRTable()
            tableHeader.Height = 20
            tableHeader.Width = (rep.PageWidth - (rep.Margins.Left + rep.Margins.Right))
            Dim headerRow As New XRTableRow()
            headerRow.Width = tableHeader.Width
            tableHeader.Rows.Add(headerRow)

            tableHeader.BeginInit()

            ' Create a table to display data
            Dim tableDetail As New XRTable()
            tableDetail.Height = 20
            tableDetail.Width = (rep.PageWidth - (rep.Margins.Left + rep.Margins.Right))
            Dim detailRow As New XRTableRow()
            detailRow.Width = tableDetail.Width
            tableDetail.Rows.Add(detailRow)
            tableDetail.EvenStyleName = "EvenStyle"
            tableDetail.OddStyleName = "OddStyle"

            tableDetail.BeginInit()

            ' Create table cells, fill the header cells with text, bind the cells to data
            For i As Integer = 0 To colCount - 1
                Dim headerCell As New XRTableCell()
                headerCell.Width = colWidth
                headerCell.Text = ds.Tables(0).Columns(i).Caption

                Dim detailCell As New XRTableCell()
                detailCell.Width = colWidth
                detailCell.DataBindings.Add("Text", Nothing, ds.Tables(0).Columns(i).Caption)
                If i = 0 Then
                 headerCell.Borders = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.Left Or DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.Top Or DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.Bottom
                 detailCell.Borders = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.Left Or DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.Top Or DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.Bottom
                Else
                    headerCell.Borders = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.All
                    detailCell.Borders = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.All
                End If

                ' Place the cells into the corresponding tables
                headerRow.Cells.Add(headerCell)
                detailRow.Cells.Add(detailCell)
            Next i
            tableHeader.EndInit()
            tableDetail.EndInit()
            ' Place the table onto a report's Detail band
            rep.Bands(BandKind.PageHeader).Controls.Add(tableHeader)
            rep.Bands(BandKind.Detail).Controls.Add(tableDetail)
        End Sub
```

By following the above example, you can set up the report layout, styles and it also illustrates how to adjust table width according to the report page width.

I suggest you to review the [How to create a report dynamically](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/AK15900.aspx) KB article (it illustrates how to adjust table width according to the report page width) and [How to programmatically create a table and manually add rows and cells](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E1333.aspx) to it example.

References:
[Create table programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109934/create-table-programmatically)
[How to create a report dynamically](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/AK15900)

> To limit the number of record to display on the page, you need to
>   follow this documentation reference. It will work in both Win Form and
>   Web form. You need to use the XRPageBreak control to achieve this
>   goal:
>
> [How to: Limit the Number of Records per Page](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument5283)

More reference on this topic:
[How to limit the number of records per page of a XTraReport using XRPageBreak Control](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q490764)
[Page Footer / How to reset page counter after each record](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q525879)
[How to display the entire group on a single page](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q564621)

Comment: Thank you sir.. But my question is that if there are two employee than each employee entry should come on new page in a single pdf file, & I am working on web application.

Comment: This code which I have given as a sample already works fine but it gives the output of all the employees on same page in a pdf file. I want that the employee with different employee code must be placed on different page but in same pdf file.

Comment: if it is web app then remember to add tag of winforms or asp.net or mvc to your question. i will look for your required changes after a while.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks once again

Comment: @Mudliar: Please check the updated answer, you can use XRPageBreak control with conditional formatting rule. i have test with sample application.. give a try with reference link and update me if you still facing problem. Have a nice time..

Comment: Thanks but I have already tried that XRPageBreak, but it is not giving me the desired output

Comment: Have you tried creating group and set it to print on the Whole page.

Comment: Yes I tried that, it's working when I generate Static report but in dynamic report that is not working.

Comment: @Mudliar: Add solution as answer to make this question answered and  will help others to implement too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer but perhaps helpful.

Ideally you want to Design your reports from the beginning so that they always handle more that one report (more than one entry / page).  So in your case, design your reports to handle more than one Employee (many pages / many employees).

Do NOT use the report headers and footers, but use Group Header and Footers instead.  Create a Grouping to isolate a single record per grouping, like your `EmployeeID` for example. Use `Add a Group` for this.

Then you put your labels in the Group Header (add one if missing), Detail band and Group Footer only. (Add the Group Footer if missing)

Then - you must set the `Page Break` property for the Group Footer to `After the band, except for the last entry`

Then you can simply restrict your query to a single Employee for a single page, or to many Employees - for a single page for each Employee.

This means you have more dynamics in your reports - from the outset - with almost no changes required.  (ie. Almost no changes than your report is at the moment, as you can re-arrange your report to suit this quite easily)